What happened to the keilim after the destruction of First Beis Hamikdash?
Inspired by this question (about the vessels of the Second Temple): I am looking for sources that discuss what happened to the vessels of the Tabernacle/First Temple.
We know from the Talmud (Horiyus 11) that the Aron Hakodesh was buried although, see Yerushalmi Shekalim 6:1. Do we have any information about the other vessels?

See Yerushalmi (Shkalim 6:1) whether the Aron was actually buried, or taken to Bavel upon the expulsion.

One of a few midrashim that state that the vessels eventually passed into the hands of Achashverosh and he used them in his feast: https://www.sefaria.org.il/Targum_Sheni_on_Esther.1.7.1-2?lang=he.

Rashi (Melachim 2, 16:14) writes that the Copper Mizbeach that Moshe made was buried:

ואת מזבח הנחשת ויקרב וגו' - אי אפשר לומר מזבח הנחשת שעשה משה שהרי
נגנז


Midrash (Bamidbar Rabba, 15:10) seems to say that the Menorah was also buried:

אמר לו הקב"ה: לך אצל בצלאל והוא יעשה אותה, ואמר לבצלאל מיד עשאה. התחיל
תמה ואמר: אני כמה פעמים הראה לי הקב"ה ונתקשיתי לעשותה, ואת שלא ראית
עשית מדעתך? בצלאל, בצל א-ל היית עומד כשהראה לי הקב"ה עשייתה. ולפיכך
כשחרב ביהמ"ק נגנזה המנורה, וזה אחד מחמשה דברים שנגנז: הארון, והמנורה,
והאש, ורוח הקדש, והכרובים. וכשישוב הקב"ה ברחמיו ויבנה ביתו והיכלו הוא
מחזירן למקומן לשמח את ירושלים

However, Avos d'Reb Nassan (41:12) provides an alternative list of the 5 things that were buried, and the implication is that the Menorah was not one of them, and lists the Menorah among the spoils that was taken to Rome.

חמשה דברים העשויין וגנוזין אלו הן: אהל מועד וכלים שבו, ארון ושברי
לוחות, צנצנת המן, וצלוחית של שמן המשחה, והמטה, ומקלו של אהרן שקדיה
ופרחיה. ובגדי כהונה ובגדי כהן משיח. אבל מכתשת של בית אבטינס שלחן
ומנורה ופרוכת וציץ עדיין מונחין ברומי.

I am not entirely certain that the Menorah referred to here is the one from the First Beis Hamikdash (which was made by Moshe and Betzalel for the Mishkan), or the one that we know was taken by the Romans upon the destruction of the Second Beis Hamikdash (see Gittin 57 and Bereishis Raba 65:22). The context implies that this is the Menorah of the First Beis Hamikdash.
